# Reference boost from CMake in CLion

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, clion

CLion 1.2, with bundled CMake 3.3.2 and MinGW-w64 4.8.4
I'm trying to reference boost in CMakeLists.txt

```
set(BOOST_ROOT "O:/Project/lib/windows/boost_1_59_0")
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR ${BOOST_ROOT}/stage/lib)

set(BOOST_COMPONENTS_NEEDED filesystem )
find_package(Boost 1.59.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS ${BOOST_COMPONENTS_NEEDED})

if(NOT Boost_FOUND)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find boost!")
endif()
```

If there is no libraries needed, so I use

```
 find_package(Boost 1.59.0)
```

boost is found and all works well.

But when I'm trying to reference libraries "Boost_FOUND" is not set

Boost libraries is built and there are following files in the O:/Project/lib/windows/boost_1_59_0/stage/lib folder

```
    boost_filesystem-vc120-mt-1_59.dll
    boost_filesystem-vc120-mt-1_59.lib
    boost_filesystem-vc120-mt-gd-1_59.dll
    boost_filesystem-vc120-mt-gd-1_59.lib
    boost_system-vc120-mt-1_59.dll
    boost_system-vc120-mt-1_59.lib
    boost_system-vc120-mt-gd-1_59.dll
    boost_system-vc120-mt-gd-1_59.lib
    libboost_filesystem-vc120-mt-1_59.lib
    libboost_filesystem-vc120-mt-gd-1_59.lib
    libboost_filesystem-vc120-mt-s-1_59.lib
    libboost_filesystem-vc120-mt-sgd-1_59.lib
    libboost_filesystem-vc120-s-1_59.lib
    libboost_filesystem-vc120-sgd-1_59.lib
    libboost_system-vc120-mt-1_59.lib
    libboost_system-vc120-mt-gd-1_59.lib
    libboost_system-vc120-mt-s-1_59.lib
    libboost_system-vc120-mt-sgd-1_59.lib
    libboost_system-vc120-s-1_59.lib
    libboost_system-vc120-sgd-1_59.lib
```

What I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because you want to build it your project with MinGW, but your libraries are compiled for Visual studio (you can see it from `vc120` in libraries name).

You must build boost with MinGW-64 (you can use the same stage/lib folder because names are different).

Open the MinGW console and follow the same compilation step that you use for Visual Studio, but change toolset from `msvc` to `gcc`.

Comment: don't forget to add `address-model=64` if you build for a 64 bit machine.